# Docusign API review failed due to polling

Tags: docusignapi

When I tried to do review before go to live in DocuSign, I was getting polling violation. My application uses embedded DocuSign with buyer will sign the embedded docusign and then seller will do the signing of same envelope Docusign.

So through application code I am taking the envelope id of the buyer signed envelope and passing to seller through app (all signing through application only).

So if seller sign the same envelope within 15 min(request to same envleop id), this polling violation happened.

But my application need this.

Maybe for passing review purpose If I do the request after 15 min and make it success also, after got to live if same thing happened, is there any problem?

How to solve polling violation in review before go to live?

Answer (score 0):

First, read the [Go-Live troubleshooting page](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/go-live/troubleshooting/) if you haven't already.

What I think what you are doing is this:

1. API call - create envelope
2. API call  - get embedded signing for buyer
3. **API call - check envelope status**
4. API call - get embedded signing for seller
5. **API call - check envelope status**

All of these within 15 min, which is what causing the violation.

Note that the issue is checking the status of the envelope twice within 15 min, not any API call. I would consider using the [Connect webhook](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/webhooks/connect/) to determine the status of the envelope and eliminate the need to make multiple API calls to figure this out.

Comment: I got polling violation at /restapi/v2/accounts/###/envelopes/####/documents/certificate - Polling violation with Trace ID 1. In my application I am not checking status. If buyer sign the docusign, then signed field in db will be 1. and if buyer signed then only seller signature button will popup. But each time signing completed by buyer/seller, code is there to download the signed doc.

Comment: Sounds like you're downloading the certificate twice within 15 minutes. Calls to `/envelopes/xxx-111-222/documents/1` then `/envelopes/xxx-111-222/documents/certificate` would not trigger a polling violation, but two calls to the same envelope's certificate would.

Comment: Also, highly recommend you use API version 2.1 and not v2 as v2 is old and does not get all the features/updates.

Answer (score 0):

When the first signer completes the embedded signing ceremony, the signer's browser is redirected (by DocuSign) back to your application. And the `event` query parameter tells your app what happened during the signing ceremony (was it completed or something else).

At this point your app knows that the first signer finished. You can then make one call to DocuSign for the envelope status to confirm that the envelope was indeed signed by signer 1. (You should make the call since the redirect could have been spoofed by an attacker.)

Now you know that the envelope was signed by signer 1. You can now provide the signing ceremony to signer 2.

If you want your code to poll something to find out if signer 1 is done or not, you could poll a flag that your app sets for itself. You can't poll DocuSign more often than once per 15 minutes per envelope.

### Also

> Maybe for passing review purpose If I do the request after 15 min and make it success also, after got to live if same thing happened, is there any problem?

***Don't do that!*** DocuSign also monitors applications in production and your app will be stopped at some point. The solution is to architect your app so you don't poll DocuSign. If you need to, you can poll your own app's database as often as you want. But I would recommend message passing instead.